# ExpandableListView android:dividerHeight между группами элементов?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

как выставить расстояние между группами элементов в ExpandableListView? ничего толкового по инету так и не нашел, мне нужно чтобы между child было одно расстояние, собственно оно есть, методом запихать 1 layout с цветом в другой, но теперь нужно сделать расстояние между группами, по такому же принципу не срабатывает потому что уезжает галочка обведенная кругом, как можно сделать это все по человечески, чтобы она была по центру серой области? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В документации говорится [ссылка](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView#xml-attributes) что ExpandableListView может использовать xml атрибут Android:dividerHeight. Ты пробовал его использовать в разметке, без результатно? Тогда нужно смотреть на код и разметку.

Comment: Да, пробовал, оно применяется так же и к дочерним элементам